# Understanding PhoneGaps automatic PushNotifications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am learning with this tutorial to send notifications: http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/.

It seems really easy but very limited.. So this way I can only send a notification manually with Node. But what if my app has to send a notification everytime something is updated in my database? Is that possible? Is it possible to send the notification if the user is not using the App at the moment?

All help appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) could help for your purpose.